# Building a NavigationList when JSON boolean is true with ForEach

Tags: foreach, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationview

Just learning to code so I appreciate the help here.  Trying to build a NavigationLink when JSON key boolean value = true.  Using ForEach to go through the loop but the resulting list seems to build based on the value of the last array in the JSON value.

Thank you so much for any assistance!

```html
import SwiftUI

struct ChecklistView: View {
    
    //reference the view model
    @ObservedObject var model = TitleModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            
            //loop through each title
            ForEach (0..<model.titles.count) { index in
                
                List(model.titles) { r in
                    
                    //only show those that are true
                    if model.titles[index].checklists == true {

                        
                                NavigationLink(
                                    
                                    destination: DetailView(detail:r),
                                    label: {
                                            HStack(spacing: 20.0) {
                                                Image(r.image1)
                                                    .resizable()
                                                    .scaledToFill()
                                                    .frame (width: 50, height: 50, alignment: .center)
                                                    .clipped()
                                                    .cornerRadius(5)
                                                Text(r.title)
                                            }
                                    })
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChecklistView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChecklistView()
            .environmentObject(TitleModel())
    }
}
```

JSON DATA

```html
[
    {
        "category": "Medical",
        "title": "STAT-MD",
        "ID": "1.0",
        "checklists":true,
        "preflight":true,
        "taxi_takeoff":true,
        "en_route":true,
        "app_land":true,
        "postflight":true,
        "weather":false,
        "non_normal":true,
        "maintenance":false,
        "customer_service":false,
        "fleet": "All",
        "stage": "All",
        "image1": "STATMD1",
        "image2": "",
        "image3": "",
        "image4":"",
        "pub1": "FOM",
        "reference1": "17.4",
        "pub2": "",
        "reference2": "",
        "pub3": "",
        "reference3": "",
        "remark": [
            "Updated 9/23/2022."
        ]
    },
    {
        "category": "Turbulence",
        "title": "Turbulence",
        "ID": "1.0",
        "checklists":false,
        "preflight":true,
        "taxi_takeoff":true,
        "en_route":true,
        "app_land":true,
        "postflight":true,
        "weather":false,
        "non_normal":true,
        "maintenance":false,
        "customer_service":false,
        "fleet": "All",
        "stage": "All",
        "image1": "Turbulence1",
        "image2": "",
        "image3": "",
        "image4": "",
        "pub1": "FOM",
        "reference1": "",
        "pub2": "",
        "reference2": "",
        "pub3": "",
        "reference3": "",
        "remark": [
            "Updated 9/23/2022."
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You would normally put the List and then the ForEach inside it, but you can also directly do it without the ForEach, and the if check is not necessary if you don't want to do anything with the ones that do not have checklists, so you can directly filter them then.

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model = TitleModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(self.model.titles.filter( { $0.checklists })) { title in
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: Text(title.title),
                    label: {
                        Text(title.title)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

class TitleModel: ObservableObject {
    let titles = [Title(checklists: true), Title(checklists: false), Title(checklists: true)]
}

struct Title: Identifiable {
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let checklists: Bool
    
    init(checklists: Bool) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.title = UUID().uuidString
        self.checklists = checklists
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Marc.  Can you share the topic/SwiftUI name of your fix so I can do some research on it?

Comment: Sorry, not quite sure what do you mean

Comment: Just looking for a topic that I can search to learn more about the code you provided.

Comment: but which part of it doesn’t sound familiar to you? The view is very similar to what you had and the structs I guess you also had something like that?